# No tty in shell buffers in Carbon Emacs on High Sierra

Tags: osx, shell-mode

I've been using the Carbon Emacs port of Emacs, which is based on Emacs 22, for many years. I know it's way out of date and unmaintained, but I have a huge collection of home-grown extensions that I took with me when I left a job two decades ago, and some of them aren't compatible with modern Emacses.

Last week I upgraded my MacBook from El Capitan to High Sierra. Emacs is still working fine except for one thing: shell buffers no longer have a tty. I guess something changed in the way that applications get a pseudo-tty, and Emacs doesn't know how to do it.

I generally do all my command-line work in shell buffers rather than Terminal windows (which I just use for logging into Linux servers for work), so this is really annoying. I can't use `sudo` since it requires a tty to ask for the password, and many applications change their behavior depending on whether stdin/stdout is a tty (e.g. `ls` doesn't show its output in columns, `python` doesn't show interactive prompts).

I know I'm going to have to bite the bullet one of these days and upgrade to a recent Emacs version (Carbon Emacs is 32-bit, and Apple has announced that these will no longer be supported in an upcoming release). But I was wondering if someone knows a quick fix I can use to remedy this one thing while I work on switching.

Comment: You may have a version of this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53531777/cannot-open-pty-under-mac-os-high-sierra/53581958#53581958

Comment: Yes, sounds the same.